# I can't read data from ajax with jstree

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, jstree

I am sending data from database to the page with Ajax. I want to show this data with jsTree. There are as many folders as the number of data I send. but it doesn't show their names. How can I properly display data with jsTree?

[image]

[image]

My JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/anaKategori",
            success: function (data) {
                
                console.log(data);
                createJSTrees(data);
               
            },

            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });

    function createJSTrees(json) {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': json
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "data", "ui"]
        });
    }
```

My C# code (.net core 5.0):

```
public List<tumKategoriler> anaKategori()
        //public string anaKategori()
        //public IActionResult anaKategori()

        {
            foreach (var item in context.urunKategorileri.ToList())
            {
                if (context.urunKategorileri.Any(x=>x.urunKategorileriUstId == item.urunKategorileriId))
                {
                    List<altKategoriler> p = new List<altKategoriler>();


                    foreach (var altItem in context.urunKategorileri.Where(x => x.urunKategorileriUstId == item.urunKategorileriId))
                    {
                        altKategoriler e = new altKategoriler
                        {
                            ad = altItem.urunKategorileriKategoriAdi
                        };
                        p.Add(e);
                    }

                    tumKategoriler i = new tumKategoriler
                    {
                        ustKategoriAdi = item.urunKategorileriKategoriAdi,
                        AltKategoriAdlari = p
                    };
                    json.Add(i);
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    tumKategoriler o = new tumKategoriler
                    {
                        ustKategoriAdi = item.urunKategorileriKategoriAdi
                    };
                    json.Add(o);

                }
               
            }

            return json;
            //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
            //return Json(new { jsonvar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json) });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure may be wrong.You can try to return `List<JsTreeModel>` in `anaKategori`:

```
public class JsTreeModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Parent { get; set; } = "#";

    }
```

If it doesn't have a parent,Parent="#".If it has a parent,set parent's Id. to Parent property.

Here is sample data:

```
[{
                        id: "padre1",
                        parent: "#",
                        text: "Padre 1",
                    }, {
                        id: "padre2",
                        parent: "#",
                        text: "Padre 2"
                    }, {
                        id: "id3",
                        parent: "padre1",
                        text: "Figlio 1 di padre 1"
                    }, {
                        id: "id4",
                        parent: "padre1",
                        text: "Figlio 2 di padre 1"
                    }, {
                        id: "id5",
                        parent: "padre2",
                        text: "Figlio 1 di padre 2"
                    }, {
                        id: "id6",
                        parent: "id5",
                        text: "Figlio 1 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
                    }, {
                        id: "id7",
                        parent: "id5",
                        text: "Figlio 2 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
                    }, {
                        id: "id8",
                        parent: "id5",
                        text: "Figlio 3 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
                    }, {
                        id: "id9",
                        parent: "#",
                        text: "Figlio 3 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
                    }]
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I the url of ajax code you missed the file type.
*********************************your ajax

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/anaKategori",
            success: function (data) {
            .
            .
            .
```

*****************************try giving extention of file as here in url

```js
$.ajax({
                url : 'test.php', //like this
                type : 'post',
                data : {'data':'1'},
                .
                .
                .
```

hope you have got the results by this fix, thank you

Comment: hi. i am pulling the data from the method, not from the page. The page I gave at the address does not exist. I am using .net core. I also shared my backend codes in the question section. you can look.